# A question about Zarisky set of a generated Ideal in $R:= \mathbb{C}[x_1, \dots ,x_n]$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $R:= \mathbb{C}[x_1, \dots x_n]$ and consider $S\subseteq R$. Then I want to prove that if $I$ is the ideal in $R$ generated by $S$ (denoted $I(S)$) then we have that $Z(I) = Z(S)$, where

$$Z(S) = \{p \in \mathbb{C}^n \, | \, f(p)=0 \, , \, \, \, \,\forall f \in S \}$$

Now, if $S \subseteq R$ the ideal generated by $S$ is

$$I(S)= \{a_1f_1 + a_2f_2 + \dots+a_rf_r | \, \, a_i \in S \, , \, f_i \in R\}$$

since $R$ is a *noetherian* ring. So

$$Z(I(S)) = \{p \in \mathbb{C}^n \, | \, \lambda(p)=0 \, \, \forall \lambda \in I(S)\}$$

but then $\lambda(p) = (a_1f_1 + \dots a_rf_r)(p) = a_1(p)f_1(p) + \dots a_r(p)f_r(p)$.

I'm just not too sure about this last step, but it yields the result since any zero for $f$ will be a zero for $a$ and vice-versa.

Comment: Is Noetherian really needed here? It always holds that $V(S) = V(\langle S\rangle)$. One inclusion is trivial.

Comment: Yes, you don't need the ring to be Noetherian here. The fact that $R$ is Noetherian tells us that we can always replace $S$ by some finite set. (which is important, but it has nothing to do with this question)

Comment: Got it, so even if I have an infinite family of generators $a_1f_1 + a_2f_2 + \dots$ the result obviously keeps holding by applying the definition of additions and multiplications inside the ring $R$. Many thanks.

Comment: The mathematician in question is Oscar **Zariski**, not Zarisky.

Answer (score 1):

We take $p\in Z(S)$, then $f(p)=0$ for all $f\in S$. Then every linear combination in $I(S)$ has the form and vanishes in $p$, because $\sum a_k \underbrace{f_k(p)}_{0}=0$ for some $a_k\in R$. Thus $Z(S)\subset Z(I(S))$.

Now let $p\in Z(I(S))$, that is $g(p)=0$ for all $g\in I(S)$. Let $f$ be any element of $S$, then $f=1\cdot f\in I(S)$ so that $f(p)=0$. Hence $Z(I(S))\subset Z(S)$.